# Django runserver shows just blank page

Tags: python, django, web, django-models

I am currently trying to setup the Django web app from https://github.com/fiduswriter/fiduswriter.

When I run `python manage.py runserver localhost:8000` I do not receive any errors. The ouptput of the console looks as follows:

```
python manage.py runserver localhost:8000
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, avatar, bibliography, contenttypes, document, feedback, flatpages, sessions, sites, socialaccount, style, user, usermedia
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
Transpiling...
May 03, 2020 - 21:32:04
Django version 2.2.10, using settings None
Django tornado server is running at http://localhost:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

When accessing localhost:8000, there is no page coming up.

However, when I build the Docker image resp. pull the one from https://hub.docker.com/r/moritzf/fiduswriter/, I can start it and it shows the starting page.

How is this phenomenon explicable?

Comment: What do you see printed to the console?

Comment: HI @Chris , I added the code fragment above.